# Build Array from String in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have string like this `1-male,2-female`
I want to make this as array like following

```
array(
    1 => male,
    2 => female
);
```

i can make this by using foreach
Ex:

```
$str1 = '1-male,2-female';
$outPutArr = array();
$arr1 = explode(',' $str1);
foreach($arr1 as $str2){
    $arr2 = explode('-', $str2);
    $outPutArr[$arr2[0]] = $arr2[1];
}
```

Is there any other short cut to do this?

Comment: No... nothing wrong with what you did...

Comment: @Neal
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509040/build-multidimensional-array-from-string-php

See this Post. I want some thing like this.

Comment: @rkaartikeyan this loses the values of the keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a simple regex and [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to simplify it down to:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)-([^,]+)/', $input, $matches);
$array = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

[`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) mixes it back to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => male
    [2] => female
)
```

Another common approach is utilizing `parse_str()` after `strtr()` to replace whatever delimiters your string has into `=` and `&`.

Comment: Hai Bro thanks for your Answer. But What is Input? and Matches? What i have to put there?

Comment: `$input` is your `$str1`, while `$matches` is a result variable and by-product that you don't have to provide.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work, although I didn't test it. It's just another way of doing it to give you more options:

```
$String = "1-male,2-female";
$Array = array();
foreach (array_chunk(explode(array('-', ','), $String), 2) as $Ar)
  $Array[$Ar[0]] = $Ar[1];
```

How it works:

It splits the data into an array of this form:

```
array('1', 'male', '2', 'female')
```

That's what the explode is for. Then it rearranges it into [chunks of 2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) like this:

```
array(array('1', 'male'), array('2', 'female'))
```

Last, in a foreach, it merges each array into it's first element (key) and second element (value).

```
array('1' => 'male', '2' => 'female')
```

Note that, if an array key is repeated, the value is overwritten.